# Virtual Router software is keep on disconnecting

Tags: wi-fi

I'm using the Virtual Router from my laptop to connect my android mobile through WIFI. It's connecting properly but the connection is not extending more than 5 - 6 minutes. Is i have to change any settings in the mobile? OR is any other software providing this kind of service. I have SAMSUNG Young Model number : GT-s5390, Android Version : 2.3.5.

Comment: Do other devices maintain longer connections with your laptop?

Comment: No Idea. I never connect with other devices..